# PHPUnit Success callback function?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

While lurking through docs of PHP Unit I found function that should be called if test fails, namely `onNotSuccessfulTest`.
But is there a function or any method I could use to indicate that test was successful?

For example I have 3 tests, `TestOne`, `TestTwo`, `TestThree`. While i can determine if one of tests where successful, can I check if All of them ended with success and do action depending on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I can't see any straightforward solution, here is one of less ugly alternatives to try.

**Write a 'fake' test that depends on testOne, testTwo and testThree**:

```
class DummyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        self::assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function testTwo()
    {
        self::assertTrue(false);
    }

    public function testThree()
    {
        self::assertTrue(true);
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     * @depends testTwo
     * @depends testThree
     */
    public function testOnAllTestsSuccess()
    {
        echo 'All tests have succeeded';
    }
}
```

`testOnAllTestsSuccess` will be run only in case all those it is dependant on pass, otherwise it will be skipped.

Comment: If it will run ONLY when alla tests succeed, then that's what I'm looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To run a function after a successful test you can use the following workaround:

```
    // Teardown is a function that gets run after each test
    public function tearDown()
    {
        // Status 0 is returned on a successfull test
        if ($this->getStatus() == 0) {
            // stuff to do on sucsess
        } 
    }
```